# How to upload only new images in Edit pages using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I don't know how to distinguish　downloaded images and new images in one array.

```
struct PostEditor: View {
   @Binding var post:Post
   @State var selectedImages = [UIImage]()
   @State var selectedImage: UIImage?

   init(post:Binding<Post>){
      self._post = post
      self._selectedImages = State(initialValue: _post.wrappedValue.imageUrls.map({ 
            imageUrl in
            if let url = URL(string: imageUrl){
                if let data = try? Data(contentsOf:url){
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data){
                        return image
                    }
                }
            }
            return UIImage()
        }))
   }

   var body: some View {
       ScrollView(.horizontal){
            LazyHStack(spacing: 16){
                ForEach(selectedImages,id: \.self)
                { img in
                        Image(uiImage:img)
                }
                ForEach(0..<(4 - selectedImages.count),id: \.self){ _ in
                    Button(action:{
                        isShowAction.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.rectangle.badge.plus.fill")
                    }
                }
            }
        }


   }.sheet(isPresented: $imagePickerPresented, content:{
                ImagePicker(image: $selectedImage)
            
        })
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $isShowAction) {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("confirm"),
                        message: Text("please select"),
                        buttons: [
                            .default(Text("photo Library"),action: {
                                imagePickerPresented.toggle()
                            }),
                            .cancel()
            ])
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedImage) { newValue in
            guard let selectedImage = selectedImage else{ return }
                selectedImages.append(selectedImage)
        }

}
```

In this above code, to display images regardless of downloaded images or new images, I use `UIImage` type's array. That is `selectedImages`.
It means downloaded image's type would change `string` type image URL to `UIImage`.
I use `UIImagePickerController`　wrapped by `UIViewController` getting Photolibrary.

But this array's `selectedImages` can't distinguish　downloaded images and new images.
So I have to upload all images in selectedImages array.
I don't want to upload downloaded images. I want to upload new images in this pages.

How do I change `UIImage` array's selectedImages?
What should `selectedImages` be?

Comment: You could try to use a separate `struct model` for your images, that includes a property
 `isNew`. For example: `struct PostImage { var isNew: Bool; var images: [UIImage];...}`.
Then use `@State var selectedImages = [PostImage]()` etc... and test if `isNew` or not
 before displaying.